# Docker sampling measurements in python

Tags: python, docker, cpu-usage, measure

I want to get data about CPU usage by my apps working in docker containers.
I want collect data with time with accuracy in ms.
I found the docker api lib in python where I can get info from `docker stats`.
I wrote something like this

```
import docker 
import time

client = docker.from_env()
con = client.containers.get("docker-tutorial")
cpu = []

for i in range(0,10):
    status = con.stats(decode=None, stream = False)
    cpu.append([status['cpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['total_usage'], time.time()])
```

I have get that info what I want but the time between my measurement is about 2s, it is too long.
Is there any way to do this faster in python or in other way?
I am working on windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where those two seconds are coming from, but when I try to run it as follows:

```py
import docker
import time

client = docker.from_env()
con = client.containers.get("docker-tutorial")
cpu = []

for status in con.stats(decode=True, stream=True):
    cpu.append([status['cpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['total_usage'], time.time()])
```

I get a result every one second instead of every two seconds.

This [seems to be a lower limit](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23188) though, so I don't think you can do better.

If you want to limit to just 10 entries you can `zip` with the `range`:

```py
import docker
import time

client = docker.from_env()
con = client.containers.get("docker-tutorial")
cpu = []

for _, status in zip(range(10), con.stats(decode=True, stream=True)):
    cpu.append([status['cpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['total_usage'], time.time()])
```